# How to create a html table cell using comma separated value in php

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have few comma separated values .I have added it to an array name 'meter_status' .I exploded it 
I want to add these data to html table row ,in the way in one cell i have to split it and display it

I tried with the following code. But it is not display in td format what can be the issue

```
$each=explode(',',$meter_status);
$count= count($each);
$status.='<td rowspan="'.$count.'">';

    foreach( $each as $link){
        $status.= $link;
    } 
$status.='</td>'; 
return $status;
```

Comment: Really you need to have this as part of a complete table with the correct format of <table> then <tr> then <td> - is the code either side of this snippet in that format?

Comment: yes it  is part of complete table. i want to display this data in one cell with different row

Comment: Why don't you use `$status.= $link.'<br>';` then?

Comment: try:- `foreach( $each as $link){
                                     $status .= "<tr>".$link."</tr>";
                                 } `

Comment: in next column related data will be there , it is adding to a databtable

Comment: try : `foreach($rowData[0] as $key=>$value) {echo "<td>".$value."</td>"}` It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
  $each=explode(',',$meter_status);
  $count= count($each); ?>
        $status.='<td rowspan="'.$count. '"'
  foreach( $each as $link){
        $status .= <<<TEXT 
            <tr>
                <td>$link</td>
             </tr>
TEXT;
      } 
    return $status;
```